# Denormalizing and adding multiple ids to one row

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm currently working on a SQL Server relational database which will be accessed through the Entity Framework. I have a couple of questions that I cannot seem to find proper answers to.

Please see my database model diagram:

[image]

**1.**
I'm not quite sure if the `ProblemType` implementation is the right way to go. As it has been set up now, both columns allow null values in `ProblemType` since it will either contain a `ProblemTypeRoadID` or a `ProblemTypeVandalismID`. So the question is really if it is possible to de-normalize the model by removing the `ProblemType` table and relate both `ProblemTypeRoad` and `ProblemTypeVandalism` in the `ProblemDesc` table?

**2.**
Looking at the `Problem` table you will find a column named `HistoryIDs`. This column should contain a comma-separated string with all the `HistoryIDs` related to a `Problem`. A `HistoryID` is essentially a `ProblemDescID` (since a `ProblemDesc` gets its `IsHistory` column set to true whenever it is updated) as the `ProblemDesc` is copied whenever changed.
My question is: what is the best way to add multiple `ProblemDescIDs` to the `HistoryIDs` column? If it was something like "1,5,7" it would be easy to find all the histories for a given `ProblemDesc`.

**3.**
Any other suggestions for the diagram is also very welcome :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Please consider the revised diagram:**

[image]

Now that you have given me some great suggestions for improvement, I have tried to implement most of your suggestions. `ProblemType` has been removed and `ProblemHistory` added. Changes have also been made to how `WorkerComment` and `Media` relate to their parent tables.
Would this implementation work?

Thanks!

Comment: #2: **don't do this!** this violates even the **first normal form** of database design: a cell (row/column) should contain **at most one value** (and one value only - or nothing) - but **never** multiple values! Cramming multiple ID's into a comma-separated string is going to make selecting these values later on a messy hell ! Don't do this - seriously - just don't. ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can remove the problemtype table, and just relate problemtyperoad and problemtypevandalism to the problemtype table with the problem type id
2. No, it shouldn't. You should have a table ProblemHistory with columns ProblemID and HistoryID with a row for each History.
3. It seems you can have a worker comment that relates to multiple problems. Should it be the other way around? Similarly for media and ProblemDescs. Can only one worker work on a problem? Also, MSSQL has a geography type that you can use instead of CoordinateLat and CoordinateLng.

Comment: I'm currently working on your suggestions (will post new diagram as soon as I'm done). Just to answer 3. A WorkerComment should only be related to a single Problem and the same goes with Media and ProblemDesc. A Problem can only have one Worker assigned, but a Worker can work on multiple Problems.